# Call Python function from Erlang Code

Tags: erlang, mqtt, erlang-ports

I am working on MQTT broker (http://www.emqtt.io), which is written in Erlang. I have a use case where I need to call one of my python module from emqtt broker code written in erlang.

I have already checked into the google about **erlport** (http://erlport.org/) which is use for port communication between erlang and python. It works well in erlang shell but when I use the same in emqtt erlang code then it does not work. It throws an error shown below

```
17:22:40.073 <0.717.0> [error] gen_server <0.717.0> terminated with reason: call to undefined function python:start()
17:22:40.073 <0.717.0> [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.717.0> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: call to undefined function python:start() in gen_server2:terminate/3 line 1151
17:22:40.073 <0.631.0> [error] Supervisor emqttd_session_sup had child session started with {emqttd_session,start_link,undefined} at <0.717.0> exit with reason call to undefined function python:start() in context child_terminated
17:22:40.073 <0.677.0> [error] Supervisor 'esockd_connection_sup - <0.677.0>' had child connection started with emqttd_client:start_link([{packet,[{max_clientid_len,512},{max_packet_size,65536}]},{client,[{idle_timeout,30}]},{session,...},...]) at <0.716.0> exit with reason call to undefined function python:start() in context connection_crashed
```

We are calling python module from emqtt plugins code, change of code is show below

```
on_message_acked(ClientId, Message, _Env) ->
   io:format("client ~s acked: ~s~n", [ClientId, emqttd_message:format(Message)]),
   io:format("client ~s",[python:start()]),
   {ok, Message}.
```

Please help us.

Comment: Have you compiled first your python module? it seems like maybe it isn't compiled or you don't have an exported function start/0.

Comment: The issue here is that erlang cannot find erlport (i.e. not in the ERL_LIBS environment variable)

Comment: @Rei I have put the same in vm.args environment file of MQTT

Comment: @A.Sarid I have compiled it and put it in the MQTT broker as well as  it is erlport code. Whoever has downvoted first do the same at your end and then do downvote. The question is valid and i think no one ever has trried it with MQTT.

Comment: So it may be a path issue. Are you sure you're pointing to erlport correctly? Try using an absolute path.

Comment: @Rei I have done that too but now I have overcome with my issue by putting erlport source code in plugins folder of EMQTT and then I have compiled EMQTT now it is working fine for me.